# Typescript doesn't infer correct type with Generic extending string union type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
type Test = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

function foo<T extends Test>(arg: T) {
  if (arg === 'a') {
    console.log(arg);
  }
}
```

like this.. I expect arg inferred 'a' in if block.

but ts infer as just T.

why this situation?

I think that `extends` keyword has something...

Comment: Interesting. If you write `arg: string` then it does narrow correctly, so it's definitely to do with T being a type variable. But if you don't have an `extends` clause then it thinks `T` and `string` have no overlap, so there is no way to test whether it's caused by `extends` specifically. It seems like a bug, but maybe there is a reason for it.

Comment: While the question itself might be interesting, the generics in above example is useless. Just use `function foo(arg: Test) ...`

Comment: @AlekseyL. You can presume that this is just a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue, not the actual use-case.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that your type `T` is not `Test` but is a subset, we can say every type which can be used instead of `T`, and every for union means a type which has the same or less union members. Consider example type which extends `Test`:

```
type Test = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type SubTest = 'b' | 'c'

type IsSubTest = SubTest extends Test ? true : false // evaluates to true
```

As you can see `SubTest` doesn't have `a` member but it is assignable to `Test`, therefore we can use `foo` function with such a type.

```
const arg: SubTest = 'b'
foo(arg)
```

Everything good, no error. But that means that your condition `arg === 'a'` will never be met, as there is no member `a` in `SubTest`, that is why TS cannot assume that inside the condition we work with `a`, as in this situation this branch is totally not reachable and inside it will be type `never`. We can even write such function and check:

```
function foo(arg: SubTest) {
  if (arg === 'a') { // compilation error, condition will be always false
    console.log(arg);
  }
}
```

Ok but even though why TS is not narrowing to `a`, as the condition is clear anything which will pass it will be `a`, no doubt here!

Lets try reproduce manually the same type guard which exists in the original condition, and the condition checks if the left value say x (which extends from Test), equals to the right value say y(which extends Test)

```
function isTestMember<X extends Test, Y extends Test>(x: X, y: Y): x is Y { 
  return x == y  // error we cannot compare member of X with member of Y
}
```

As you can see such typeguard cannot be even written. As X and Y can not overlap, therefor the condition `x === y` is not valid for all members of `X` and `Y`

In summary TS cannot consider conditions on types which can not overlap as type guards, therefor type is not narrowed.

Comment: If you define `function isTestMember<Y extends Test>(x: Test, y: Y): x is Y { return x == y }` then the `foo` function works fine, and `arg` is inferred as type `T & 'a'` inside the `if` block. So I don't think the fact that the condition isn't always satisfiable for some `T` really matters.

Comment: But x is not Test but `T extends Test`

Comment: So what? `x` is assignable to `Test`, since `x: T` and `T extends Test`. Just because `T & 'a'` might not be populated doesn't mean we can't narrow `x` to that type after an appropriate type guard; here it is, working without errors. [Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=32&pln=7&pc=41#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oHICGaoB90CNs80BjNAbgChqAzAVwDsTgBLAewahfjkQFkIAW3wQATgB4YUCAA9gEBgBN4sBMAB8AChkAuVYgA0UEHpgBKPTK4qpAbyiiIwOqM5XkqEFAC+tRs3ZOGjY2SWk5BWV9DU0MUQBzUzMoW0ooLhooTW5eYAFhMViEo0w0M2TU9PSSDng2ABsIADp6tnii+LMqdN9fIA)

Comment: In that case the return type of the `isTestMember` call is inferred as `x is 'a'`, and it narrows `x` to type `T & 'a'`, so the question is why doesn't `arg === 'a'` work the same way.

Comment: `T & 'a'` can evaluate to `never`, when we have such type like `SubTest` it will be exactly `never`. `T & a` is not any better then just `T`

Comment: What I am showing in the typeguard is exact situation which is in `if`, but in typeguard we have error, in if we dont have, I suppose it was design decision

Comment: Just because it can evaluate to `never` doesn't mean it's a problem. `T` itself could be `never`. Of course `T & 'a'` is a stricter type than `T`, because it's assignable to type `'a'` whereas `T` is not assignable to `'a'`.

Comment: I agree that your type guard fix the situation. But still its kind hack, as you are just treating T as just Test, and in real life its a subset.

Comment: No, it's not treating `T` as `Test`, nor is it a hack. It's just calling a function which accepts `Test` with a value of type `T`, which is fine because `T` is a subtype. There is no reason for your type guard to have `x`'s type as a type parameter, and the error in your `if` statement is an artefact of your choice to make it a type parameter. Your type guard is not the "exact situation" as the OP's `if` condition; if it was, the OP's code would have the same error (or a similar one) on the `if` condition, but the OP's code has no errors.

Comment: Fact is that when you have `<X extends Test, Y extends Test>` then you cannot do comparison between member of X and member of Y, and this is the exact case, the condition is not valid for all pairs `(X,Y)` its valid only for some.

Comment: You **can** do a comparison between a member of X and a member of Y... your `isTestMember` does that comparison in the line `return x == y;` where `x: X` and `y: Y`. If your reasoning were correct, there would be an error in your `isTestMember` function.

Comment: I put there `Y extends T` pay attention, if you say `Y extends Test` you have the error I am talking about.

Comment: The OP's code does such a comparison in the condition `arg === 'a'` and it is not an error. It is perfectly valid to compare values where the types sometimes might not overlap. You seem to be arguing that the comparison is invalid because *sometimes* (i.e. for some instantiations of `T`) it will always be false; but when something is only *sometimes* always false, that just means it is sometimes false. There is no problem with writing a condition which is sometimes false.

Comment: The thing is that TS sometimes allow for the comparison of not overlapping types, and sometimes not, I think this is design decision. As you can see in typeguard I cannot compare not overlap types, I can in the condition. The result is in condition there is no error, but it doesnt work like type guard, in type guard is the error.

Comment: Maybe there is minimum requirement for being a typeguard, and this requirement is not met here.

Comment: I think this is that, condition is valid, but is not valid type guard as it works for types which can not overlap