# Picking a type from an interface map based on map key

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, typescript-generics

I want to code a general create method that produces different objects that are typed inside of a map. The problem is that typescript mixes all interfaces together instead of only selecting one in the interface map:

```
interface A  {
  a: string;
}

interface B {
  b: string;
}

interface ABMap {
  a: A;
  b: B;
}

function create<ID extends keyof ABMap>(id: ID): ABMap[ID] { // this is now combined A & B instead of A | B
  if (id === 'a') {
    return {a: 'a'}; // error a is missing b key 
  } else if (id === 'b') {
    return {b: 'b'};
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that the if statements do not narrow the type of `id`, it still has type `ID extends "a" | "b"` within the branches.

Comment: I have currently fixed the error using this helper `type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];` and then returning `ValueOf<ABMap>`. but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Here is an [issue mentioning the problem](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36772), though having the type `ID & 'a'` probably would not be helpful either, it would need to be narrowed to just `'a'`.

Comment: Also, the question is then sort of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60204107/typescript-doesnt-infer-correct-type-with-generic-extending-string-union-type/60206029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, typescript does not narrow the definition of the generic based on type guards.  This is a known and expected behavior, although it can be frustrating.  When you check `if (id === 'a')`, typescript knows that the value of the variable `id` is of type `A`.  However it does not narrow the generic to just `A`.  It is perfectly valid for the generic type `ID` to be the union `A | B` and the variable `id` to be `A`.  So when that check is passed, we know that `ID` must include `A`, but we don't know that it is "`A` and only `A`".

The second issue is why the type `ABMap[ID]` is getting narrowed to `A & B` instead of `A | B`.  That one I cannot explain.

There are (at least) three solutions.

1. You can do what you have done which is broaden the return type to `ABMap[keyof ABMap]` aka `A | B`
2. If you are dealing with a small set of pairings, like the two in this example, you can associate the inputs and outputs through function overloads:

```
function create(id: 'a'): ABMap['a'] 
function create(id: 'b'): ABMap['b'] 
function create(id: keyof ABMap): ABMap[keyof ABMap] {
  if (id === 'a') {
    return {a: 'a'};
  } else {
    return {b: 'b'};
  } 
}
```

3. You can keep your generics and tell typescript that what you are returning is in fact the right type by using the `as` keyword.

```
function create<ID extends keyof ABMap>(id: ID): ABMap[ID] {
  if (id === 'a') {
    return {a: 'a'} as ABMap[ID];
  } else {
    return {b: 'b'} as ABMap[ID];
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILOQbwLACgNwBcyAzmFKAOYDceAvnnqJLIigEJZ4YBGxZFEDXqNczaPCRp2AWTgAHLvmRE0tZX2Tt1DXHhgBXEAjDAA9iGQIoEOJADiAHgCSAEWQQAHpBAATEsgA1hAAnmYw0nLyAHwAFMC%20xG4AlMSosgoA2m4AukoYwBHxvsgAvOXIAORwlcn5GMg2YAZQlpiq1ZV0KgHpUdmuOeoY3RAANiQoOMoYTS1tmpU8XT2RWbnDyLq6%20kYm5pbWtpAA8sXEnalr8pmdebvGphZWNnYQZwkXy1d9WUuV91whkeBxex3e5yCoXC1x%20GRuwTCEV%208jy0wKRQSZQql3qswgzVaWA6NTom1GEym3AacyJmEWyzJ1O6Ij0uAQFjIKkoaTKYLe9lil3UHJAXLgZl5pX5pyFNWSIs5YGQPB5Wj5RwFQu%20irFyp4kvV0s1sv%20CqAA)